# Qual comando para limpar memoria no Android

Tags: android, xml

Estou utilizando ImageView que sao chamadas por botões a carregar as imagem enche a memoria constando esse erro java.lang.OutOfMemoryError  teria um comando que limparia a memoria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você carregar as imagens, use o código abaixo:

```
((BitmapDrawable) yourImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
```

Comment: ainda não resolveu, você não saberia como carregar apenas uma imagem na memoria por vez.